# jQuery alternative to each?

Tags: jquery, json, each

I'm using an each function in several places because i'm displaying multiple results, but in this instance I know I only have one result, however I still need to convert data.results to index.value for use later on in the function and sending value to other functions.

```
function displayGameDetails(data){  
    $returnedData = processObjects(data);
    var  $gameDeveloperName = $returnedData[0];
    var  $gameDeveloperURL = $returnedData[1];
    var  $gamePublisher = $returnedData[2];
    var  $gamePublisherURL = $returnedData[3];
    var  $gameFranchises = $returnedData[4];
    var  $gameDeveloperName = $returnedData[5];
    var  $gameImageURLS = $returnedData[6];

    $.each(data.results, function(index, value){ //this is where there will only be 1 result
        var $boxArt = validateBoxArt(value);
       var $releaseDate = trimDate(value, "DMY");

        $('#game-title, #purchase-amazon').append(value.name);
        $('#game-synopsis').append(value.deck);
        $('#game-release-year').append($releaseDate);
        $('#game-box-art').append('<img src="' + $boxArt + '"/>');

        $.each($gameDeveloperName, function(index, developerValue){
            $('#game-developers').append('<li><a href="' + developerValue + '">' + $gameDeveloperName + '</a></li>');
        });

        $.each($gameImageURLS, function(index, imageValue){
            $('#image-carousel').append('<div class="item">' +
                                        '<img src="' + imageValue + '" alt="test">' +
                                        '</div>');
        });
    });
}
```

What can I replace the each function with so that value will still be defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
value = data.results;
```

This is a workaround that I came up with but it's not very efficient.